# UIBezierPath not cleared on redraw

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-graphics, uibezierpath, drawrect

I have custom `UIView` in which I draw a UIBezierPath. This view is used in a UITableViewCell. So when I scroll, the custom view's bezier path gets redrawn. The problem is that the new path draws over old path drawings (the context isn't cleared properly). I'm calling `setNeedsDisplay()` on the table cell fetch and I've also set `clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true` for the view. The only thing that clears up the old drawing is calling `context.clear(rect)` but this isn't at all ideal since I lose the background (it becomes black).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
class CustomView: UIView {

var percentage: CGFloat = 0 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true
    contentMode = .redraw
    clipsToBounds = false
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    // NOTE: don't really like doing this
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.clear(rect)

    let center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width/2, y: self.bounds.size.height/2)

    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                            radius: self.bounds.size.width/2-10,
                            startAngle: 0.5 * .pi,
                            endAngle: (-2.0 * self.percentage + 0.5) * .pi,
                            clockwise: false)

    path.lineWidth = 4
    UIColor.red.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
}
}
```

This is where my cell and custom uiview gets set.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let num = list[indexPath.item]
        let percentage = CGFloat(num) / 10
        cell.customView.percentage = percentage // Custom view should get redrawn after this call
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: "I can provide code if needed" Obviously it is.

Comment: updated the post

Comment: ok, question now is much better, thanks

Comment: So if I understand the problem, all the percentage views look good initially, but then you scroll and cells are reused, and now you get a mess. Is that right?

Comment: Yea, pretty much. The first time I scroll through the cells, they draw correctly. When I start scrolling back, left and right, they start drawing over each other. For example, I'll see different numbers like "1" and "5" drawn on top of each other.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, I can't reproduce it. I made a project and used pretty much your code, and what I see is that each row's drawing stays as it is when I scroll. - Now, that said, your code look pretty nonviable. Your `cellForRowAt` doesn't even compile. And it would help to know what `list` is. And finally, your circles are _huge_; I can't believe you really mean that.

Comment: So I noticed that scrolling slowly, the problem goes away. Rapid scroll causes the overlapping to happen.

Comment: By stays as it is, do you mean each cell's drawing is the same? Or the overlapping doesn't happen?

Comment: how about drawing background before drawing the path? UIColor.white.setFill();
            context.fill(rect);
           // context.clear(rect)

Comment: That's clever. It does work. But the overlapping issue really bugs me. My suspicion is that there's a timing issue. If I ask for the redraws too quickly (by scrolling very fast), things go wrong.

Comment: Well you've got these huge circles that go onto the next cell, and you do not clip to bounds. That is totally incoherent. I didn't do that in my version, you may be sure! I had no overlapping, and that was by design. Clip to bounds. Draw each cell inside itself only!

Comment: I draw the circle with a radius that's half the width of the view and centered in the center of the view. That still draws outside of the UIView?

Comment: By the way: "but this isn't at all ideal since I lose the background (it becomes black)." You can fix that by saying `self.backgroundColor = .clear` in your `init`.

Comment: All I can tell you is that I had to alter your code considerably in order not to see nothing but circle fragments

Comment: Wow, the `backgroundColor = .clear` fixed everything. I didn't provide all the code, didn't think anyone would try to run it. But I appreciate it.

Comment: Added that to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is merely that your drawing is huge and strays outside the cell because your views do not clip to bounds. That's incoherent. Each cell needs to draw just its own content.

In other words, the overlapping you are seeing has nothing to do with the custom view drawing; it has to do with the *cell* drawing. You are infecting the neighboring cells with your drawing.

By the way, you say:

> but this isn't at all ideal since I lose the background (it becomes black)."

You can fix that by saying `self.backgroundColor = .clear` in your `init`.

Comment: Could you point me to the section/page in your book that talks about `backgroundColor = .clear`? Thanks.

Comment: First look in the Index under "views, black background", which takes you to a discussion in chapter 2 on Drawing. Then read the Erasing section of chapter 2 on Drawing.

Comment: Got it. Question, when a redraw happens, does the previous drawing go to the background? When I set `backgroundColor = .clear`, the black background and the previous drawing _both_ go away.

Comment: As I said, I couldn't reproduce the issue where the previous drawing doesn't go away. `draw` always starts from scratch. That is why, in my answer, I suggest that the problem is caused by the drawing of the cell rather than the custom view.

Comment: I see. Did you clip to bounds for the cell, the custom view, or both?

Comment: As I told you earlier, I drew inside the custom view so I didn't _need_ clip.

Comment: ok, I actually set clipToBounds for the cell _and_ the custom view and it's still overlapping. Somehow setting background = clear makes the overlap go away. Curious...

Comment: Very interesting, but you didn't provide enough info for me to reproduce what you are really doing so I can't test more than I have, sorry. I don't know what `list` is, I don't know how `customView` is situated within the cell, and I don't see why your code compiles at all (because I would have thought that `cell.customView` would throw an error). I had to make a _lot_ of assumptions to get something that would actually compile and run, and of course those assumptions could be wrong. You didn't supply an MCVE. You just supplied _some_ code.

Comment: @matt Holy carp I have been investigating this issue where a custom shadow flashed for all cells every time two cells switched, even when calling reloadRowsAt(). It wasn't even dequeuing the other cells, they flashed also. It was because the shadow left the frame of the cell, and even though cell.clipsToBounds was false it still clipped the shadow while updating other parts of the table. Thank you